# Non abelian groups with a prime number of one-dimensional representations

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, finitely-generated

I am interested in examples of nonabelian groups that are "finitely generated by elements of finite order" that have a prime number of one dimensional representations.

For $p=2$ we have $S_N$ for $N\geq 2$. For $p=3$ we have $A_4$.

> What about other primes?

I am just as interested in small $p$ examples and general results. I am not looking for complete classifications for all $p$ or indeed any $p$.

I understand that there is an "at least $p$" result [for groups of order $p^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4031962/number-of-inequivalent-one-dimensional-representations-of-a-group-of-order-pn) but I am looking for equality rather than inequality.

Comment: You are looking for groups with $|G/[G,G]| = p$, and it would be hopeless to try and classify even finite groups with that property. There are far too many.  Also, for any example, you could get further examples by taking direct product with  perfect groups, which could be either finite, or even something like a Tarski Monster.

Comment: @DerekHolt thank you: I am interested in isolated examples including for small $p$... not a complete classification for any $p$ or all $p$.

Comment: The problem is that there are far too many examples.

Comment: I would be interested in even one concrete example for e.g $p=5$. Is there an example for every $p$ (not concrete)?

Comment: Yes, I answered that  in my first comment. A concrete example for $p=5$ is $C_5 \times A_5$. Another one is the (unique) nonabelian group of order $55$.

Comment: @DerekHolt fantastic, thank you. If you want to convert that comment to an answer I would accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Derek Holt says we can take the direct product of a cyclic group and a perfect group.